Principles and Techniques in Combinatorics by Chuang Chong Chen Chapter 1 Problem 41
$$
\mbox{Let}\ X = \left\{1,2,\dots,n\right\},\quad
\mathscr{A} = \left\{A\subseteq X \mid n\notin A\right\}\quad\mbox{and}
\quad\mathscr{B} = \left\{A\subseteq X \mid n\in A\right\}
$$

Show that $\left\vert\mathscr{A}\right\vert = \left\vert\mathscr{B}\right\vert$ by the $bijective\ principle$.

I do not know where to start. I don't know how to use the bijective principle for these types of problems.

Hint. Let $A$ be a subset that does not contain $n$. Can you think of a straightforward way to change it to a subset that does contain $n$?

I'm allowed to modify a subset?

@Michele you're allowed to find a bijective function between $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ and by fundamental principles of counting, if there exists a bijective function between the two they must have the same number of elements.

@JMoravitz yes, but how do i use the bijective principle. I know that I need to establish that it is injective (B has exactly one A) and that it is surjective (every B has some A) to show that it is bijective. But, how do I do this?

List all  $8$ subsets of ${1,2,3}$. Then look for a (generalizable) way to pair the ones without $3$ to the ones with $3$. If you can do that there must be $4$ of each.

@EthanBolker Yes I will try this. But, to show that it holds by bijective principle, i need to show that it is injective and surjective

Let's use a test case with $n=3$. Let's define a mapping from $\mathscr{A} \to \mathscr{B}$
$$\begin{align*}
    \{1,2\} &\to \{1,2,3\} \\ 
    \{1\} &\to \{1,3\} \\ 
    \emptyset &\to \{3\} \\ 
    \{2\} &\to \{2,3\} \\ 
\end{align*}$$
For the general case, define a map $f: \mathscr{A} \to \mathscr{B}$. Notice that $f(A) = A \cup \{n\}$. Thus, we have shown since this shows that for every $\mathscr{B}$ there is one $\mathscr{A}$ which shows that $|\mathscr{A}| = |\mathscr{B}|$ by (BP) $\blacksquare$

Don't say "Notice that ...". It's not something to notice after you have defined $f$, it is the very definition of $f$. Then actually prove that $f$ is injective and surjective from the definitions of those terms. That's obvious from the example but at this stage of your education you should spell out the steps.
